# Symfony login without form, weird behavior

Tags: php, security, symfony

I one action controller of my project (Sf 2.7.3), I autologin a user like that:

```
$providerKey = 'user_provider';
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

$loginevent = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $loginevent);
```

Thats it's seems that works fine. In the Symfony toolbar appears:

> Logged in as mail@example.com
>
> Authenticated No
>
> Token class `UsernamePasswordToken`

My security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    
    frontend:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        provider: user_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: user_login
            check_path: user_login_check
            use_referer: true
        logout:
            path:   user_logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key:      *****
            lifetime: 31536000


access_control:
    - { path: ^/private-zone/login,         roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/private-zone/login_check,   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/private-zone/register,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/private-zone*,              roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN] }
    
providers:
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class:        X\AccountBundle\Entity\User
            property:     email
            manager_name: ~
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
encoders:
    X\AccountBundle\Entity\User: { algorithm: sha512, iterations: 10 }
```

But if I go to the /private-zone path, it's redirecting to /login (infinitely).

If I login with the form login, everything works fine, and the toolbar info is the same. Anyone understant the problem?

Comment: Are you inside a controller or what?

Comment: I would suggest to comment out `use_referrer` just to make a try and let me know

Comment: @DonCallisto yes, inside a controller.

Comment: @DonCallisto the same happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://knplabs.com/en/blog/redirect-after-registration-in-symfony2), the `$providerKey` argument of `UsernamePasswordToken` is the name of the firewall, so change `$providerKey` to `'frontend'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

According to your toolbar, you are not authenticated. This might happen when you provide no roles to a user/usertoken. There is a difference between having a token, and having an authenticated token.

This might be the reason your private-zone login fails: it needs the user or admin role, or an anoymous token (or higher) that is authenticated.

Make sure that '$user->getroles();' returns at least one role, and see if a) authenticated is yes on the toolbar and b) fixes your login issue private-zone

Comment: The `getRoles` return the roles well. When I stay in a url that not need to be authenticated, allways show me "Authenticated No", but if I go to a authenticated zone, show me "Authenticated Yes". I think that it's the normal behavior. The problem was in the `$providerKey`. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is the normal behaviour. I assumed the toolbar showed this on an authenticated page.